# floating point exception in c program

Tags: c, exception, floating-point

while running this code I am getting floating point exception pls explain why it  is coming so.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int gcd(long int, int);
int main() {
    int t, n, a, i;
    long int abc;
    scanf("%d", &t);
    while (t--) {
        abc = 1;
        scanf("%d", &n);
        abc = n * (n - 1);
        for (i = n - 2; i > 1; i--) {
            a = gcd(abc, i);
            abc = ((abc * i) / a);
        }
        printf("%ld \n", abc);
    }
    return 0;
}
int gcd(long int a, int b) {
    if (b == 0)
        return a;
    else {
        return (b, a % b);
    }
 }
```

Comment: icantunderstandthiscodebecauseofthelackofindentation

Comment: itsokicanreadthingslikethatorrathereclipseosrteditout

Comment: What input do you provide to the program?

Comment: Go on, give us a clue. What statement gives the exception?

Comment: "Mysterious floating point exception" usually turns out to be *integer* division by 0 (doesn't make sense, but that's how it works)

Comment: There is no floating point number anywhere in this program.

Comment: this line: return (b, a % b); seems to be trying to return a%b, however, ',' separated operations are executed left to right, so the result of 'b' (the first operation) is discarded.  The compiler should have raised a warning.  You need to have all warnings/errors enabled and fix them.

Comment: this line: scanf("%d", &n); will probably fail because no effort has been made to consume the intervening newline. Also, the returned value from I/O functions, including scanf() need to be checked to assure successful operation.  suggest: if( 1 == scanf(" %d", &) ) {...}  note the leading ' ' in the format string, which will consume all leading whitespace, including the newline from entering the prior number

Comment: i have given input 1 4

Answer (score 4):

The else part in `gcd` function is bogus.  You probably wanted to call `gcd` recursively and instead you are returning `a % b`.  And as a result if `a % b == 0` you divide by 0 on line 13.

The expression `(b, a % b)` is evaluated as two subexpressions separated by comma operator.  The value of b is forgotten and the value of the whole expression becomes `a % b`.

The correct version:

```
int gcd(long int a, int b) {
    if (b == 0)
        return a; 
    else {
        return gcd(b, a % b);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change a few things:

1) `if(a == 0)` instead of `b==0` and `return` variable `b`

2)  Use recursion `gcd(b%a, a)`

```
if (a == 0)
       return b;
    else {
        return gcd(b%a, a);
    }
```

And you can also use this short version

```
return  a ? gcd(b%a,a) : b;
```

Proof:

We have `m = n * (m div n) + m Mod n`.

This equation is correct even `if n = 1`, because `m div 1 = m` and `m mod 1 =0`.

If `n` and `m` mod n it's multiple of `d`, also `m` is multiple of `d`, because `n * (m div n)` and `m mod n / d`.

On the other hand if `m` and `n` is multiple of `e`, to because `m mod n = m -n * (m div n)` is also multiple of `e`.